# Confusion with complete objects and sub-objects

Tags: c++

```
class A { 
 int x; 
};

class B : public A {
 int y;
};

B b;
```

I know `b` is considered a complete object of `B` and the object that `B` contains is a sub-object of `A`.

But someone pointed me to this,

Paragraph 3, of C++ Standard 1.8

> (1.8/3) For every object x, there is some object called the complete
>   object of x, determined as follows: — If x is a complete object, then
>   x is the complete object of x. —  Otherwise, the complete object of x
>   is the complete object of the (unique) object that contains x.

In this, I'm finding the wording the very confusing with all those `x`s all over the place, Can you explain this with my example?

Comment: Where is that excerpt from? I've never heard that complete-object subobject gobbledygook. They call them objects and classes where I come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is the complete object of `b`, `x`, `y` and the `A` subobject of `b`.

Comment: do you mean `b` is the complete object of `B`? I don't get how `b` is complete object of `b` itself?

Comment: @user: You can also just say that `b` is *the* complete object.

Comment: I see now, didn't notice that its speaking for every object in the universe.

Comment: @user: Haha. :p "*the*" wrt this question. Else it would be `int b = 42;`.

Answer (score 3):

It sound to me that by "complete object" they are referring to the object that was returned by the new operator, or placed onto the stack as a local variable.  For example, if we start with your code (above), b is the complete object for x.  How did we get that?  By working our way up the hierarchy:

1. Is (x) its own complete object?   No, it is a member of A, and thus
   a part of a larger object.
2. Is (A) its own complete object?   No, it is a superclass of B, and
   thus a part of a larger object.
3. Is (B) its own complete object?   Yes, because the object b was
   declared as being of type B.

(If b had instead been part of a still-larger object, then we would have had to go further up the hierarchy to find the complete object)

Comment: Nice hierarchical explanation. +1

Answer (score 3):

The quote is from the C++11 standard, 1.8. More completely:

> 2) Objects can contain other objects, called subobjects. A subobject can be a member subobject (9.2), a base class subobject (Clause 10), or an array element. An object that is not a subobject of any other object is called a complete object.
>
> 3)  For every object x, there is some object called the complete object of x, determined as follows:
>
> - If `x` is a complete object, then x is the complete object of `x`.
> - Otherwise, the complete object of x is the complete object of the (unique) object that contains `x`.

In other words, consider this:

```
struct A { }; struct B : A { };

A x[10];
B y;
```

Now `x[1]` is an object whose complete object is `x`, and `y::A` is an object whose complete object is `y` (and both subobjects are of type `A`).

It's just terminology...